# I cannot know where VScode find JAVA_HOME environment variable

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-home

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI2K3.png)

I installed and uninstalled jdk-14 and install jdk-13
But vscode recognize JAVA_HOME environment variable as "jdk 14" and this is non-existing path.
Also, I set the JAVA_HOME as jdk-13 path and write to .zshrc too.

Although reloading and restarting vscode, vscode still recognize JAVA_HOME as jdk-14 path.
Where vscode find $JAVA_HOME variable?? There is never my terminal.

Comment: There are plenty of questions and matters about how to set JAVA_HOME, have you searched before asking?

Answer (score 0):

`File -> Preferences -> Settings`

Here search for `JAVA_HOME`. You should see the below option. 
[image]

Now search for `java.home` and you will see the value that VSCode has set already

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Umm... but  "java.home" in settings.json is also "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home"
and it is right path...

Comment: Can you open `Terminal` in VSCode and `echo $JAVA_HOME`?  or `echo %JAVA_HOME%`. What value does that give? It is probably a factor of the environment variables set in the shell from where your VSCode instance starts

Answer (score 0):

From the picture you have given out. you have set the jdk path for extension correctly, but you really set the 'JAVA_HOME' system environment as 'jdk 14'.

Could you please tell me the meaning of 'vscode recognize JAVA_HOME environment variable as "jdk 14"'? How do you get 'JAVA_HOME' variable?

The 'java.home' was set for the extensions:This JDK will be used to launch the Java Language Server. And by default, the 'java.home' will be used to compile your projects. from:[here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#setting-the-jdk).
and it really has no relationship to "JAVA_HOME" at all.